# Is it possible to do code coverage of human QA actions in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, testing, code-coverage

We got a project from another team and a set of test cases that we are suppose to evaluate if they are good enough.

I want to do a dry-run of all the test cases and check what is the coverage without write all the cases in OCUnit first.

Is there any easy way to approach this?

Comment: What format are the current test cases you received from the other team?

Comment: Just a list of reproduction steps to reproduce in a paper, nothing automatic :(

Comment: Apparently, gcc42 was removed from Xcode 4.2 so that's why gcov cant be used, anyway, clang implemented gcov compatible features, I'm checking how to activate them, I hope to come back with a solution soon